# Amazon Aurora with different statistics between writer/reader

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm using some tables like `pg_stat_user_tables` and to optimize `pg_stat_user_indexes` our indexes and I found that this table it's different between the `writer` and `reader`.

Someone knows why this happens? And which table we can trust for tunning?